# Is separation provided in class F airspace?

Tags: icao, separation, class-f-airspace

According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airspace_class) on different airspace classes, separation is provided for IFR/SVFR to other IFR/SVFR in class F airspace. In ICAO [Annex 11](http://dgca.gov.in/intradgca/intra/icao%20annexes/an11_cons.pdf) from 2018 (p.36 in the pdf file), I can't find anything about separation being mentioned.

> Class F. IFR and VFR flights are permitted, all participating IFR flights receive an air traffic advisory service and all flights receive flight information service if requested.

I'd like to know if I have missed something and the Wikipedia page is right nevertheless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**RE I can't find anything about separation being mentioned:**

Check appendix 4 on PDF page 103 (APP 4-1):

The third column is for the separation provided, where for Class F it is:

> IFR from IFR as far as practical

[image]

And click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl02n.png) for the full table (red highlight mine).

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I need to practice my search skills in these type of documents!

Comment: @schn: You're very welcome. On the page you found, refer to 2.6.3. It refers to that appendix ;) Also if a more helpful answer comes along, feel free to change the accept (check mark).